# A function $f$ is measurable iff $f^{+}$ and $f^{-}$ are

Tags: measure-theory

Consider a function $f$, and the following two functions: $$f^{+}(x) = \max\{f(x), 0\};\\f^{-}(x) = -\min\{f(x),0\}.$$ We claim that $f$ is measurable if and only if both of the above functions are measurable.

One direction is trivial: namely, if both $f^{+}$ and $f^{-}$ are measurable, then because $f = f^{+} - f^{-}$ it follows that $f$ must be measurable.

The other direction is what I am unsure on. I think it should follow from the fact that if $f$ is measurable, then $f^{-1}([a,\infty])$ is measurable, and because $f^{+}$ takes on strictly positive values, it follows that the inverse image of $f^{+}$ over this interval is also measurable.

Thoughts?

Comment: max = sup, and supremum of two measurable function is measurable, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For any $a$, 
$$(f^+)^{-1}((-\infty;a])=\{x: \max\{f(x),0\}\leq a\}=\{x: f(x)\leq a\}\cap\{x: 0\leq a\}=$$
$$=f^{-1}((-\infty;a])\cap\begin{cases}\varnothing, & a<0\\ \mathbb R, & a\geq 0\end{cases}$$
Instead of $\mathbb R$ shold stay the space where $f$ is defined. This intersection is measurable for any $a\in \mathbb R$, so $f^{+}$ is measurable.

The same for $f^{-}(x)$.